# Error with using ORB-SLAM2

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, slam

I was trying to get my hands dirty with SLAM and I started with ORB-SLAM2 library.

I have downloaded a TUM sequence and wanted to use ROS for it. So I am following the steps according this [page](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2).

In Step 7, part 2, when i run `./build_ros.sh`, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/../../../Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/../core/optimizable_graph.h:41:0,
                 from /home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/../../../Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/../core/base_vertex.h:30,
                 from /home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/../../../Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/types_seven_dof_expmap.h:34,
                 from /home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/../../../include/LoopClosing.h:34,
                 from /home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/../../../include/LocalMapping.h:26,
                 from /home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/../../../include/Tracking.h:31,
                 from /home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/../../../include/System.h:29,
                 from /home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/src/AR/ViewerAR.h:29,
                 from /home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/src/AR/ViewerAR.cc:21:
/home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/../../../Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/../core/jacobian_workspace.h:36:24: fatal error: g2o/config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/MonoAR.dir/build.make:198: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MonoAR.dir/src/AR/ViewerAR.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MonoAR.dir/src/AR/ViewerAR.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I went and checked the `g2o` folder and there is a file by name `config.h`.

So why am I still getting the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `CMakeLists.txt` in `/home/sarvagya/Desktop/Swaayatt/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/`

Try adding

`${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../Thirdparty`

to the list of `include_directories()` at `line 44` (it should be at that line if you did not change the file)

Adding this line tells the cmake where to find the `g2o/config.h`.

Answer (score 0):

From the information, that missing `g2o/config.h` in `jacobian_workspace.h`, but when I look into the file, and do not find the `include` in line 36. Do I miss something, or you change something?